# Handling bad input with a Class

Tags: java

Here's a constructor I have for Electronics that checks if the State input is valid.

```
public Electronics(String name, double price, int quantity, double weight, boolean frag, String s)
    {
        super("Electronics",name,price,quantity,weight);
        fragile=frag;
        s=s.toUpperCase();
        if(checkState(s)==true)
        {
            state=s;
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("ERROR - not a valid state abbreviation");
        }
    }
```

However in my `main()`, I have something like this:

```
public List<Item> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Item>();
temp= new Electronics(name,price,quantity,weight, fragile, state);
...
shoppingCart.add(temp);
```

So even if the state abbreviation is not valid, (it just prints out that state is not valid) but the object is still added to the ArrayList. What can I do to stop the add if the state abbreviation is not correct?

Comment: If it's an invalid state abbreviation shouldn't you instead of just printing an error message actually throw an IllegalArgumentException? That way you would prevent the addition to the list and also preventing that an object is created without a state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [throw an Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) and handle it in your `main()`, [IllegakArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is probably the best fit here.

Something like:

```
    ...
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }
    ...
```

in main:

```
public List<Item> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Item>();
try { 
   temp= new Electronics(name,price,quantity,weight, fragile, state);
   ...
   shoppingCart.add(temp);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { 
  //handle exception
}
```

Note that if the exception will be thrown by the constructor, the program will not reach the insertion of the element to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw an exception. An IllegalArgumentException sounds like the one. Then I'd the constructor throws an exception don't add it to the list

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is only meant to initialize your instance variables.have a seperate method class check make it return an boolean variable.
Constructor Initializing your instance variables:

```
public Electronics(String name, double price, int quantity, double weight, boolean frag, String s)
    {
        super("Electronics",name,price,quantity,weight);
        fragile=frag;
        s=s.toUpperCase();
    }
```

Method which checks if a call to thecheckState() returned true:

```
public boolean check(){
if(checkState(s)==true)
        {
            state=s;
           return true;    
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("ERROR - not a valid state abbreviation");
            return false;
        }
}
```

In main method:

```
public List<Item> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Item>();
temp= new Electronics(name,price,quantity,weight, fragile, state);
...
if(temp.check()){
shoppingCart.add(temp);
 }
 else {
  //check returned false
  }
```